# Data storage with javascript on clients computer?

Tags: javascript, storage

Anybody knows ways to store data with javascript clients computer? Except using cookies.

May be there is such lib ?

By the way the data I want to be stored isn't secret if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HTML 5 Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). It's what the Stack Exchange network uses for global authentication. It's supported only by modern browsers but you could always gracefully fallback to cookies if not supported (IE8+, Chrome, Safari, FireFox 3.6+, and Opera 10.61+ are all supported).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "normal" js cookie method: http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/document.htm#cookie
or if you want to use a lib jquery with cookie plugin: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about database type storage there is [google gears](http://code.google.com/apis/gears/gears_faq.html) and [adobe air](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/). These are basically browser plugins that allow you to store data locally on the client. Google have deprecated google gears in favour of the new HTML 5 local storage.