# store a var local on a pc with javascript

Tags: javascript, var

I am trying to store the highscore of a player local, on his pc itself. I don't know if this is possible and I didn't find a question about it on this site. I just have a var wich contains a number. I want to store it on his pc soo when the player plays the game again in his browser his highscore still will be available.

Comment: Luckily it is not easy to access local storage with javascript. You should rather try to store its results on a database or inside some cookies, if you're 100% sure that the user will play with the same browser from the same pc (in the cookie case)

Comment: so if it is possible with cookies, please give me an example ;-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Data storage with javascript on clients computer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742811/data-storage-with-javascript-on-clients-computer)

Comment: @briosheje *"Luckily it is not easy to access local storage with javascript"* - That's completely untrue, using local storage in JavaScript is very easy. In HTML5 there is a `localStorage` object.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek: I mean that accessing the local hard drive is not easy. My fault :P

Comment: @briosheje: actually, <input type=file> and <a download=file.ext> make reading and writing (respectively) the local hard drive trivial... it still won't be a good way to save highscores, but it's good to know about...

Comment: O sorry for dublicating, couldn`t find it.. But thnx guys

Comment: @dandavis: hopefully no one can delete your C:\ or your ~home directory through that, then!

Comment: @briosheje: no deleting (or updating), just reading and creating (for now)...

Comment: @dandavis: then a database, for such a case, would be a smarter solution, no? :)

Comment: @briosheje That would be overkill for such a simple thing, HTML 5 Web Storage or cookies would be a better idea... and a much cheaper solution.

Comment: a database would be good if more than one device needed to access the same user-created value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage` is not supported by old browser . so use cookie as a fall back.

```
if(window.localStorage)
    window.localStorage.setItem("highscore",1000);
else
   document.cookie="highscore=1000; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2018 12:00:00 UTC";
```

to retrieve the value

```
function getCookie(cname) {
var name = cname + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) 
      return  c.substring(name.length,c.length);
}
return "";
}  
if(window.localStorage)
   var highscore=window.localStorage.getItem("highscore");
else
  var highscore=getCookie("highscore");
```

Comment: localStorage works in IE8, so by "old" you mean something like "10 years old", in which case, big whoop. it's better to leave out those old foggies than slow down page loads for every single browser by using cookies... then there's all the EU rules about cookies that don't seem to apply to localStorage...

Comment: This is for me the answer because it gives me two solutions, Thnx!

Comment: thnk.And cookies has an advantage that it can be processed on the server side too..

Answer (score 4):

use localstorage:

```
window.localStorage.score="20"  // storing

window.localStorage.score  // getting the score again.
```

Comment: It may be worth mentionning that `localStorage` only stores strinsg, so if you want to store anything, `JSON.stringify` is your best friend, and to retrieve it, `JSON.parse`. Also, I prefer using `localStorage.getItem` and `localStorage.setItem` to get `null` when it does not exist (yet), but it's a personal preference I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of an odd thing to do, unless we are talking about nodeJS (?) storing to file system or some other local store.

if you'de like to persist a certain value so next load it'll be taken from a stored location on javascript you'll have to do it using cookies,
but than again it'll be cleared every time you are clearing your cookies and will no be shared across multiple browser on your machine.

that being said, this is how you store a value to a cookie using javascript:

**document.cookie="somekey=savedValue";**

**var readValue = document.cookie;**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Cookies besides `localStorage`.

```
var expDate=new Date();
var score=20;
expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate()+365); // expiration after one year

// Setting cookie
document.cookie='score='+score+';expires='+expDate;

// Retrieving the cookie
var yourOldScore = document.cookie.match(/score=(.*?)\;/)[1];
```